# Python: index of first non-matching character?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Python 2.7: I'm wondering if there's an inverted version of the index operation for a list. I can't use `index` because the value that will not match is unknown.

Here's an example:

```
myString = "aaaaaxcbaa"
pos = myString.not_index('a')
# pos should be 5
myString = "bbzcbaa"
pos = myString.not_index('b')
# pos should be 2
myString = "xxxxx"
pos = myString.not_index('x')
# this can throw an error similar to "index"
```

Does such a thing exist?

Right now I'm simply iterating the list item-by-item but it feels like this should be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

```
>>> next(i for (i, e) in enumerate("aaaaaxcbaa") if e != "a")
5
```

Comment: Works and is very elegant.

Comment: +1 but this will throw a `StopIteration` exception with strings like `"aaaa"`, etc. Simple fix is to return a default instead: `next((i for (i, e) in enumerate("aaaaaxcbaa") if e != "a"), -1)`.